# Error when declaring a number variable in a function block in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

SQL Worksheet

```
create or replace FUNCTION checkSubmitted (pStudentId IN VARCHAR, pCourseCode IN VARCHAR, pAssignmentNumber IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR
    IS output VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE mark_result NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT assignment.mark INTO mark_result FROM Assignment WHERE student_id = pStudentId AND course_code = pCourseCode AND assignment_number = pAssignmentNumber;
        IF (mark_result IS NOT NULL) THEN
            RETURN 'Submitted';
        ELSE
            RETURN 'Not Submitted';
        END IF;
END;
```

Compiler - Log

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
4/5       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue. 
12/4      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge 
Errors: check compiler log
```

I want to create a SQL check function and i need to declare a variable in the function.
Please advise how can i achieve this.

Comment: it's obvious that `DECLARE` should be removed.

Comment: Just remove `DECLARE`, that's for anonymous blocks, or sub-blocks. [See the docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-855AA11F-32CB-4CAD-9255-BE92A6821487) The second error seems to be because you don't have a `/` at the end - after the final `END;`, on a line on its own.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, your current problem is easy to fix.

However, I'd like to point you to another possible "mistake" - what will happen if there's no data for combination of those parameters' values? `SELECT` won't return `NULL` - it will raise `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception, and you should handle it. (I presume that it isn't likely for query to return more than a single value; if it is, handle it as well).

Also, try to avoid multiple `RETURN` statements. Procedures can be *long* and you might get lost in where you return and what you return. Set output variable's value (which you declared, but never used), and return it at the end of the procedure.

Therefore, consider something like this:

```
create or replace function checksubmitted 
  (pstudentid in varchar, pcoursecode in varchar, passignmentnumber in number)
return varchar
is 
  mark_result number;
  output      varchar(100);
begin
  select a.mark 
    into mark_result 
    from assignment a
    where a.student_id        = pstudentid 
      and a.course_code       = pcoursecode 
      and a.assignment_number = passignmentnumber;
      
  if mark_result is not null then
     output := 'Submitted';
  else
     output := 'Not Submitted';
  end if;
  
  return output;

exception
  when no_data_found then
    output := 'There is no data for these input parameters';
    return output;
end;
/
```